# Error starting SQL Developer

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

HI everyone.

I am trying to run sqldeveloper on my Red Hat Linux Enterprise 5 machine but get the following error:

[root@machine plugins]# sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL Developer
Copyright (c) 2006, 2007, Oracle. All rights reserved.

WARNING: error instantiating 'java.util.logging.FileHandler,' referenced by handlers, class not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.FileHandler,
<>
Exception during runtime initialization
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
<>
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
<>
[root@machine plugins]#

Do anyone have idea to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not have Java SDK installed in your machine, or your Java SDK is not properly installed. Thus, please try to reinstall the Java SDK and run the SQL Developer again.

Please refer to below web site for the system requirement and installation guide of SQL Developer.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12153/install.htm#sthref15

Answer (score 0):

The class it is looking for (i.e. [java.util.logging.FileHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/logging/FileHandler.html)) is part of the JRE (or JDK).

So, do you have any JRE or JDK (and which version) installed on your machine? Did you also set the JAVA_HOME environment variable?